# iPhone app crash [__NSCFString objectForKey:] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am trying to add in tempArray only even number of data.localBookmarks is array of dictionary. Here is my code :

```
currentIndex = indexPath.row;
for (NSDictionary *dict in localBookmarks)
    {
    if (currentIndex % 2 == 0 && currentIndex <= [localBookmarks count])
     {             
           [tempArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"firstName"]];
     }
        currentIndex++;
    }
NSLog(@"tempArray %@",tempArray);

cell.textLabel.text = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

my app crash on [tempArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"firstName"]]; this line ,How can I fix it?

Comment: Well it's pretty obvious from the error message... `dict` is actually a string (ie check that your `localBookmarks` contain only dicts)

Comment: wt is localBookMarks ?? is it NSDictionary??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why you are crashing

The variable `dict` that you think is a NSDictionary is actually a NSString. Since strings don't respond to the `objectForKey:` method your app crashed. That is what the error message is telling you.

### Where the problem lies

Your statement: "data.localBookmarks is array of dictionary" is false. At least one of them is just a string.

Check where your `localBookmarks` comes from. If it's data you are parsing you may need to change that.

Comment: Thanks David, in localBookmarks array contains string also not all the dictionaries, I got my mistake.