# '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c515c0'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

mr problem is------i am getting data from url and the data in arrayobj.when i run this project i am getting this error.what i am do wrong statement or code in project please check `connectiondidfinishloading` and `cellforrowanindexpath`.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSError *error ;
NSMutableDictionary *dictobj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataobj options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

newsobj=[dictobj objectForKey:@"news"];

//NSArray *longdeceobj=[newsobj objectForKey:@"long_desc"];

 for (NSDictionary *dict in  newsobj)
 {
    NSDictionary *title=[dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    [arrayobj addObject:title];
 }
 [[self tableobj]reloadData];
}
```

//this is cell for row at index path code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString*cellide=@"identifier";
newcustomobj=(newsCustamView *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellide];
if (newcustomobj==nil)
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"newsCustamView" owner:self options:nil];
}
newcustomobj.newstitle.text=[[[arrayobj objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"news"]objectForKey:@"title"];
return newcustomobj;
}
```

Error Is:

```
2014-05-23 18:34:04.913 newsdata[6518:90b] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c515c0
2014-05-23 18:34:04.915 newsdata[6518:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c515c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01b851e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015cb8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01c22243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x01b7550b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x01b750ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   newsdata                            0x00008a13 -[ViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 435
6   UIKit                               0x0038411f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
7   UIKit                               0x003841f3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
8   UIKit                               0x00365ece -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2428
9   UIKit                               0x0037a6a5 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
10  UIKit                               0x002fa964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015dd82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
12  QuartzCore                          0x03dcd45a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
13  QuartzCore                          0x03dc1244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
14  QuartzCore                          0x03dc10b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
15  QuartzCore                          0x03d277fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
16  QuartzCore                          0x03d28b85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
17  QuartzCore                          0x03d29258 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
18  CoreFoundation                      0x01b4d36e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
19  CoreFoundation                      0x01b4d2bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
20  CoreFoundation                      0x01b2b254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
21  CoreFoundation                      0x01b2a9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
22  CoreFoundation                      0x01b2a7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
23  GraphicsServices                    0x03c8f5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
24  GraphicsServices                    0x03c8f42b GSEventRun + 104
25  UIKit                               0x0028bf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
26  newsdata                            0x000119cd main + 141
27  libdyld.dylib                       0x02330725 start + 0
28  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: My guess withouth knowing the JSON (which you be present in your question): `[[[arrayobj objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"news"]objectForKey:@"title"];`
When do call `objectForKey` (the first one or the second one since we don't know the JSON), in reality your object is a `NSString` and not a `NSDictionary`

Comment: I think you have to paste your JSON format here so others can help in you are doing right your wrong.

Comment: thanks for reply me first i done wrong way in json format.but i learn and read some json topics and one friend suggest me u can do this way  easily solve your problem...

Answer (score 5):

The variable dictobj as you are assuming is a NSDictionary, actually it is a NSString. Since strings don't respond to the objectForKey: method your app crashed. That is what the error message is telling you. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787876/iphone-app-crash-nscfstring-objectforkey-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-inst). for more detail.

Comment: when i use this code i can solve these error                   [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c515c0
2014-05-23 18:34:04.915 newsdata[6518:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c515c0'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 1):

One of the objects that you address, of which you believe it was a dictionary, is actually a string.

Especially when parsing JSON or XML: Always double check the class of the object that you fetch and continue working with. Use `[object isKindOfClass:[ClassIThinkItIs class]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.lblTitle.text = [[dataObjectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]title];

cell.datobj.text = [[dataObjectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]date];

cell.longdicobj.text = [[dataObjectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]long_desc];

[cell.imageobj setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dataObjectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]image_file]]]
      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"songs85-56.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the json data return is a array of news dict for `news` key  dict and every `news` dict has a `title` key. So you can  try following code to show `title` in `cellForRow`:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSError *error ;
NSMutableDictionary *dictobj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataobj options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

newsobj=[dictobj objectForKey:@"news"];

//NSArray *longdeceobj=[newsobj objectForKey:@"long_desc"];

 for (NSDictionary *dict in  newsobj)
 {
    NSString *title=[dict objectForKey:@"title"]; //title may be NSString type
    [arrayobj addObject:title];
 }
 [[self tableobj] reloadData];
}
```

in CellForRow

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString*cellide=@"identifier";
newcustomobj=(newsCustamView *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellide];
if (newcustomobj==nil)
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"newsCustamView" owner:self options:nil];
}
newcustomobj.newstitle.text= [arrayobj objectAtIndex:0]; //just get title of first news, you can replace 0 with indexpath.row to show news for row.
return newcustomobj;
}
```